# If I remove a CA from Firefox, will it be back after an update?

Tags: firefox, certificate, https

If I remove a Certificate Authority from the Firefox GUI, then is it permanently removed? Or all will be back after the next Firefox update?

Answer (score 1):

If the CA came with Firefox (i.e. in the "Built-in Object Token"), you cannot delete it at all, because it's stored in read-only program code. Instead, when you click "Delete or distrust", it's copied to your personal CA list *without any trust flags*, overriding the built-in list. Thus you aren't making any changes that would be reverted by upgrades.